# Scheduler server for fire API calls at costume time

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for an existing service that provides an API call scheduler.
I want to implement scheduling in our system so that each user can determine when they will receive an email with any report.

I'm thinking of developing APIs for each report individually on our server that receives user parameters. Then after the user selects the date and time to receive the report, the scheduler will run the call to the API address at the specified time

Are there cloud-based services that receive URLs and call timings?

I found the Hangfire app but I prefer to use an existing service

Comment: You can use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) and its [API](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest) to create jobs, although keep in mind its [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/quotas).

Comment: @EmilGi tnx I will check it